# Treeview focus move with two arrow key presses

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, textblock

So I found that to make a TextBlock responsive to KeyDown I had to set Focusable="True". But now it takes two arrow key button presses to move to the next Treeview item.

How can I make the TreeView move focus with just one key press?

```
<!-- Child Item -->
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodelbase:ChildItem}">
    <TextBlock Name="childtb" Text="{Binding DisplayName}" Focusable="True" MouseDown="Open_Document" KeyDown="TextBlock_KeyDown">   
        <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="Add New Document"></MenuItem>
            </ContextMenu>
        </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
    </TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: But 2 keystrokes is the norm

Comment: Not really. If I remove Focusable="True" it moves with one. So does the treeview in Solution Explorer/Visual Studio.